# How to execute a function (identified by pointer) from lldb

Tags: c++, function, debugging, lldb

How can i call a regular function (not a block) in LLDB?

I have tried using:

```
expr int $addr = 0x51bb45
expr (void (^)(void))$addr
expr $0()
```

but i get an error 'Didn't get running event after intiial resume, got stopped instead. Couldn't execute function; result was eExecutionSetupError'

this is how the function is declared but i don't have the symbols...
extern "C" void do_something(void)

edit:

the solution is to use:

```
(void (*)(void))$addr
```

Comment: That doesn't look like a block pointer. How about `(void (*)(void))$addr` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If that is how the function is declared, then it is a block pointer not a regular function. As nos said, it would have a * in the declaration if it was a function pointer.  lldb doesn't currently know how to call block pointers: like C++ & ObjC methods they need a correctly cons'ed up artificial first argument and lldb doesn't know how to do that for blocks.

Comment: what nos said it was correct. it is not a block pointer - i am trying to run a function and just found only an example of  a block ptr.